# Mockito Spy Does Not See Correct Primitive Value

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spy

I am facing the below problem where, when indirectly updating the fields on a spy object, the spy does NOT see updates on **primitive** fields, whereas it sees on **reference** once.

As an example:

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class MyTest {

    class Actor {
        Consumer<Boolean> consumer;

        void init(Consumer<Boolean> consumer){
            this.consumer = consumer;
        }

        void act(boolean flag){
            this.consumer.apply(flag);
        }
    }

    class TestClass {
        boolean field = true;
        AtomicBoolean refField = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        TestClass(Actor actor){
           actor.init( flag -> {
               System.out.println("Changing field to " + flag);
               field = flag;
               refField.set(flag);
           });
        }

        void call(){
            this.doSomething(field);
        }
   
        void callRef(){
            this.doSomething(refField.get());
        }

        void doSomething(boolean flag){
            System.out.println("#doSomething(" + flag + ")");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        // given an actor and a spied TestClass
        Actor actor = new Actor();
        TestClass spy = Mockito.spy(new TestClass(actor));

        // when invoking the action with the primitive
        spy.call();
        // then expect correct invocation
        Mockito.verify(spy, Mockito.times(1)).doSomething( true );

       // when invoking the action with the ref field
       spy.callRef();
       // then expect correct invocation
       Mockito.verify(spy, Mockito.times(2)).doSomething( true );

       // when changing the flag to 'false'
       actor.act( false );

       // and invoking the action with the refField
       spy.callRef();
       // then expect correct invocation
       Mockito.verify(spy, Mockito.times(1)).doSomething(false);

      // when invoking the action with the primitive
      spy.call();
      // then method is NOT invoked as expected !!!!!!!
      Mockito.verify(spy, Mockito.times(2)).doSomething(false);
    }
}
```

The last verification, will fail, as the method is called with the first primitive value.

I was wondering why this is happenning? Is this an expected behaviour. Running the above test, will produce the below logging:

```
#doSomething(true)
#doSomething(true)
Changing flag to false
#doSomething(false)
#doSomething(true)
```

I would expect the last log statement to be invoked with `false`.

Any insights on the above?

PS: Version=`mockito-core:2.25.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 instances of TestClass object in your system:

- original instance
- spy instance

The spy is created from original instance.

- primitive fields (like `boolean field`) are copied, each TestClass holds
- references are copied, but underlying, referenced object is shared (`refField`)

Lets make following changes to observe that:

```
TestClass(Actor actor){
    actor.init( flag -> {
        // print referenced TestClass instance 
        System.out.println("from actor: " + TestClass.this);
        System.out.println("Changing field to " + flag);
        field = flag;
        refField.set(flag);
    });
}

@Test
public void test(){
    // given an actor and a spied TestClass
    Actor actor = new Actor();
    TestClass testClassOriginal = new TestClass(actor);
    TestClass spy = Mockito.spy(testClassOriginal);
    System.out.println("org" + testClassOriginal);
    System.out.println("spy" + spy);
  
    // when changing the flag to 'false'
    actor.act( false );
    System.out.println("After change org: " + testClassOriginal.field);
    System.out.println("After change spy: " + spy.field);
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
org: mypackage.MyTest$TestClass@4218500f
spy: mypackage.MyTest$TestClass$MockitoMock$2115616475@5c10f1c3
from actor: mypackage.MyTest$TestClass@4218500f
Changing field to false
After change org: false
After change spy: true
```

You can clearly see:

- two instances of TestClass
- actor sees the original object, not the spy
- when actor makes the change to the primitive field, it changes the original
- primitive field in the spy remains unchanged

**Possible solutions**

You need to make the actor see the spy, not the original object.
To achieve that, creation of TestClass must be decoupled from registering the consumer.

```
class TestClass {
    boolean field = true;
    AtomicBoolean refField = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    TestClass(){
    }

    void consumeFlag(Boolean flag) {
        System.out.println("from actor: " + this);
        System.out.println("Changing field to " + flag);
        field = flag;
        refField.set(flag);
    }
    // ...
}

@Test
public void test(){
    // given an actor and a spied TestClass
    Actor actor = new Actor();
    TestClass spy = Mockito.spy(new TestClass());
    actor.init(spy::consumeFlag);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Lesiak, for the detailed explanation above. It indeed answers my question. Didn't know that a spy copies over the primitive values, I had the impression that a spy was merely a proxy to the actual object. But apparently not.